# TypeLoad Exception. Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error

Tags: c#, ajax, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

At one of our production instance that is CRM 2013 Online we are getting following error in ajax call's (POST) error handler (XHR.responseText):

***"error": {
"code": "-2147220970", "message": {
"lang": "en-US", "value": "System.TypeLoadException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #0EBC6CBF"
}
}
}***

The .NET plugin code in question is working fine on our 2013 on-premise development instance with **SP1 UR2** installed. I also checked the version number and both Online production isntance and On-premise development instance are set to 6.1.2.112 version.

The plugin code is written in C# and deployed as an assembly over the Dynamics CRM. As this is happening on CRM Online I fear I can't debug the code or take traces of it?

Comment: Maybe you should update that plug-ins with the Technical Account, try with this user.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand how to update the plug-in with `Technical Account`. Can you please point towards any resource for this?

Comment: What account do you use to deploy?

Comment: Most probably the CRM org's System Administrator installs the solution and the Plugin gets deployed using this account.

Comment: If you know this user  try to update the plug-in with him.

Comment: Are you using IL Merge? If so, can you share the script you use (probably in the post-build event)?

Comment: `C:\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe /targetplatform:v4 /keyfile:../../SigningFileName.snk /out:Merged\Product.dll Product.dll Newtonsoft.json.dll`

Comment: I've recently started getting the same error, in the exact same situation.  The plugin works in 2013 on prem, and 2015 online, but it fails in 2013 online.  And it's not a new plugin, it's been working fine for a long time.
I suspect Microsoft changed or updated something on their end.  I would open a ticket with them.

Comment: FYI: Even in CRM Online, you can use the Plugin Profiler to debug plugins.  It's works great, but I use it as a last resort, because it is rather cumbersome.

Comment: We too have opened a service request with MS support.

Comment: @All I have just figured out a set of code that when I exclude from the project then the plugin executes successfully without the TypeLoad exception. Can you please suggest me that how can I isolate the type culprit for this as this is a relatively large code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the culprit - **Extension Method** - in the plugin code that was causing **System.TypeLoadException** exception on Dynamics CRM 2013 Online only.

```
    public static bool IsEqualTo<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> value, IEnumerable<TSource> compareList)
    {
        return IsEqualTo(value, compareList, null);
    }
```

Plugin fired successfully after removing this.

Extension method was working perfect on Dynamics CRM 2013 On-Premises and Dynamics CRM 2015 Online and On-premise (in sandbox modes).

As this was the large code base, thanks to the Dependency Graph feature in VS2013 that helped me in finding this by removing the classes one by one.

Comment: Extension methods work in Sandbox mode. It would have to be something that is referenced in your non-extension method IsEqualTo

Comment: Well, if this is correct then I am confused as to why it worked successfully even when I just removed `this` keyword from the IsEqualTo method.

Comment: I think it is due to when the underlying types are attempted to be loaded. Extension methods are loaded differently than static methods on other classes.

Comment: And I agree, the same code in a same managed plugin worked perfect on Dynamics CRM 2015 Online.

Answer (score 1):

Check if any external types (referenced assemblies) are being used in your plugin as these won't be supported in an online installation but may work on premise if they are being served from the GAC.

You may also be trying to perform an action that requires full trust which isn't supported in a Sandbox plugin.

Comment: External types are used but they are merged within the same assembly using ILMerge. And this is tested perfect against Dynamics CRM 2015 Online instances.

Comment: Is this could be a instance specific issue that is happening to that customer's instance only? I am asking this as I have no way to sign up a CRM 2013 Online trial.

Comment: Are you referencing the 2015 version of the sdk assemblies? If so, you may want to try referencing 2013 specific ones.

Comment: No. The development environment is on 2013 On-Premise so the referenced assemblies are of 2013. But these get installed and working perfect on 2015 Online also.

Comment: @All I have just figured out a set of code that when I exclude from the project then the plugin executes successfully without the TypeLoad exception. Can you please suggest me that how can I isolate the type culprit for this as this is a relatively large code base.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are doing an Assembly.Load call in the static constructor of the plugin, which is not available in Sandbox mode, which is what CRM Online requires.

**EDIT:**

I would create a support case with Microsoft and provide the reference number, and you'll be able to look at which reference is actually breaking.

Comment: No, the Assembly.Load is not called anywhere. I just double checked. And also the same is working perfect on 2013 On-Premise and 2015 Online

Comment: Is this could be a instance specific issue that is happening to that customer's instance only? I am asking this as I have no way to sign up a CRM 2013 Online trial.

Comment: @All I have just figured out a set of code that when I exclude from the project then the plugin executes successfully without the TypeLoad exception. Can you please suggest me that how can I isolate the type culprit for this as this is a relatively large code base.

Comment: Are there any non System.* references in your plugin class library project (including references to other projects in the solution)?

Comment: Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation. But it is merged into the original DLL using ILMerge.

Comment: Have you gone through this post? http://jerhome.blogspot.de/2014/04/ms-crm-2011-plugin-sandbox-mode.html

Comment: I went through the post and apparently doesn't seem any of this is implemented in the code.

Comment: If I was you, I would add or take away references in your code until I found the culprit. Unless you want to post the code...

Comment: Did you open a case with Microsoft? They are free, and they might be able to tell you exactly what the reference is that is breaking it

Comment: I can share the code if anyone interested to look into this. But as this is a large code base I have to upload it somewhere. We have already an open ticket with MS support on behalf of our customer but MS support are coming up with lame excuses on this - " ... no support for 3rd party solutions ... , 2013 Online is soon going to be phased out .... "

Comment: That was an extension method causing TypeLoad exception in plugin code. Details mentioned in my answer. Many thanks.